# Minecraft Dockerization

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minecraft

I'm trying to Dockerize a Minecraft Server on my VPS and I'm having a hard time with it, I can't seem to be able to get the image to put the files in the bind on my VPS host system and it can't find an execute the .jar file, I'm managing this through Compose so I will get into more details with it.

Just as I thought I understood Docker and Compose

My structure is simple I have a root directory in my VPS home user named `live`, the user of my VPS is `opc`.

- live/docker/Dockerfile
- live/docker/server.properties
- live/docker/eula.txt
- live/docker-compose.yml

The `server.properties` and `eula.txt` files are default generated ones.

Here is my `Dockerfile`,

```docker
FROM openjdk:21-slim as base

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN mkdir -p /opt/minecraft-server

WORKDIR /opt/minecraft-server

RUN wget https://api.papermc.io/v2/projects/paper/versions/1.20.2/builds/318/downloads/paper-1.20.2-318.jar -O server.jar

COPY eula.txt /opt/minecraft-server/eula.txt
COPY server.properties /opt/minecraft-server/server.properties

EXPOSE 25565
EXPOSE 25575

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  minecraft-server:
    build:
      context: "./docker/minecraft-server"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    working_dir: "/opt/minecraft-server/"
    command: "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui"
    container_name: "minecraft-server"
    ports:
      - "25565:25565"
      - "25575:25575"
    volumes:
      - "./minecraft-server/:/opt/minecraft-server/"
```

First the command that I'm executing is `docker compose build minecraft-server` and then `docker compose run -d minecraft-server`

During the `docker compose run -d minecraft-server` is where the crash happens and I get the following,

```
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container minecraft-server  Created                                                                                                   0.0s 
Attaching to minecraft-server
minecraft-server  | Error: Unable to access jarfile server.jar
minecraft-server exited with code 1
```

It's probably worth it to note that the `./minecraft-server` bind is created on the host VPS filesystem.

Comment: Your `volume` mount is overwriting all the work you did in the `Dockerfile`. Are you sure you even need a volume mounted?

Comment: @Phil hmm, what do you mean by overwriting, doesn't it simply expose the /opt/minecraft-server directory from inside the container and reflects the files to my host system at ./minecraft-server, that's intriguing...

Comment: Nope, it mounts your local directory at the location specified (`/opt/minecraft-server`).

Comment: Intriguing... so is there a way in docker to do what I described above?

Comment: So a named volume in this case is the solution for this problem thank you.

Comment: It might be but has caveats. Again, I'd question the need. What are you trying to get out of the container and on to the host?

Comment: @Phil The most important thing is that I can edit configurations and take backups of specific directories, also access other directories to upload files to them, wouldn't a docker volume prevent me from that...?

Comment: Maybe you want to mount specific files (for configuration) instead of the entire directory. As for other directories, perhaps you should mount at deeper spots, eg `/opt/minecraft-server/some/directory/i/want/to/backup`.